# How To Make an Explosion Sound with Javascript and Web Audio API Synthesizer?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, synthesizer

Being somewhat old school, I recall on the old Atari 800XL I had as a kid in the early 1980s, which was one of the first computers I used to learned programming, on how to make explosion sounds using the audio chipset, with peeks and pokes in BASIC. But now I want to teach my daughter programming, and I thought it would be fun to have her get excited by learning the steps in Javascript, with the Web Audio API, to make an explosion sound, using purely the synthesizer of Web Audio API. How does one use Web Audio API in Javascript, without an actual sound file, to synthesize a game explosion sound?

Comment: Explosions are a sudden burst of low-pass filtered white noise that gradually fades away.  Think along those lines.

Comment: This looks like some pretty good background information: https://sonoport.github.io/synthesising-sounds-webaudio.html